# Force Webforms to validate using jQuery

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form that I've added a bit of extra validation using jQuery to

```
$('#webform-client-form-27').on('submit', function(){
if ($('#edit-submitted-email-address').val() != $('#edit-submitted-confirm-  email-address').val()) {
  $('#edit-submitted-email-address').addClass('error');
  $('#edit-submitted-confirm-email-address').addClass('error');

  return false;
}
else{
  $('#edit-submitted-email-address').removeClass('error');
  $('#edit-submitted-confirm-email-address').removeClass('error')

  return true;

}

});
```

The problem I'm having is that instead of validating the whole form I'm simply returning false and stopping the whole process, is there a jQuery way that will get drupal to run it's validation checks on the other fields, so as to allow for the standard error message(s) to appear in the event that the other conditions aren't met (the other fields are just required) and add to said error message that, my custom validated field(s), don't match either?

Comment: But why you are not handling those other validation by jquery also? Validating email field by jquery and then making server call to validate other field does not make sense to me.

Comment: The two fields in specific have the additional validation because webforms doesn't offer that type of ability to set those two fields to validate separately.  They're email and confirm email fields.

Comment: just to make sure hook_form_alter() is not what you are looking for? It allows you to alter any form, it can be webform as well and add your custom validation on any field.